# What is the --reparent option of zathura doing?

Tags: x11, zathura

The first option explained in the manpage of the zathura pdf viewer is:

> ```
>    -e,--reparent=xid
>           Reparents to window specified by xid
> ```

I understand it as a way to open the pdf in an existing zathura window, but I had no luck when trying it.

What does it do? How to find out which **xid** to use? (I tried looking with `xprop`: `xprop | grep "window id"` and clicking on a zathura window.)

PS: I am using Ubuntu 16.10 with unity.

Comment: Can you add the command you tried?

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson I updated my question ;)